# Recebi nombre de variable en luigar del id con INNER JOIN validando datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo ese codigo, que me valida si un club ya esta registrado en la liga y en la division, que el mensaje lo muestro en la pagina club-registrado.php, pero me muestra el id asi:
EL CLUB TALLERES EN LA LIGA 1 EN LA DIVISION 19

Formulario html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="club" name="club" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="liga" name="liga" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="division" name="division" required>
```

la pagina club-registrado.php lo tengo asi:

```
$club = isset($_POST['club']) ? $_POST['club'] : NULL;
$liga = isset($_POST['liga']) ? $_POST['liga'] : NULL;
$division = isset($_POST['division']) ? $_POST['division'] : NULL;

require_once('conectar.ini.php');  
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT c.*, l.nombre_liga, d.division FROM club c LEFT JOIN liga l ON l.id_liga = c.liga_c LEFT JOIN division d ON d.id_division = c.division_c WHERE club = '$club' AND liga_c = '$liga' AND division_c='$division'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 0){
        $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn,$q);
        $liga = $r['nombre_liga'];
        $division = $r['division'];
    }
    else{
    //mysqli_close($conn);
    header('Location:club-registrado.php');
    }
```

pagina: club-registrado.php recibo asi para ver cual de los dos me trae en nombre.

```
$club = isset($_POST['club']) ? $_POST['club'] : NULL;
$nombre_liga = isset($_POST['nombre_liga']) ? $_POST['nombre_liga'] : NULL;
$division = isset($_POST['division']) ? $_POST['division'] : NULL;

//ese me muestra el id
<?php echo "El Club ".$_SESSION['club']." en la liga ".$_SESSION['nombre_liga']." en la division ".$_SESSION['division']; ?>

//ese no muestra nada
<?php echo "El Club ".$club." en la liga ".$nombre_liga." en la division ".$division; ?>
y me muestra asi:

En la variable de ssesion me muestra el id
asi: El Club Talleres en la liga 1 en la división 19
pero las otras variables no muestra nada.


me gustaria mostrar el nombre de la liga y el nombre de la division.
a mi me parece que no deberia usar variable de session, pero no se como traer los nombres en lugar del ID.

Se puede?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que, aunque envías una query a la base de datos, en ningún momento lees los datos que te devuelve. Si la query no devuelve ninguna fila, no haces nada y, si sí, cierras la conexión. Te faltaría al menos un `$r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn,$q);` antes del `msyqli_close($conn)`;

Por otra parte, tienes un espacio en `d ivision_c` en el `AND` del final de la query. Entiendo que sea una errata, pero seguro que te estará devolviendo algún mensaje de error.

Y, ya por último, entiendo que todo esto venga de un formulario por los `$_POST`. La variable `$_SESSION` deberías usarla si quieres recordar lo seleccionado en el formulario en posteriores clicks a la página. Para leer datos de la base de datos a partir de lo enviado en el formulario, no necesitas guardar nada en variables de sesión, lo que necesitas es recoger los datos que el servidor de bases de datos te está enviando y utilizar los datos que tendrás en el array `$r`.

Espero que con estas indicaciones lo resuelvas, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola buen dia, ahi hice los cambios que me sugeriste pero sigue igual, me trae el is o sino no me trae nada. gracias de antemano.

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra No lo entiendo. ¿qué diferencia hay entre la solución que aportas y la que sugiero?

Comment: Hola @David JP quise decir que resolvi segun lo que aportaste. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ahi pude resolver de la siguiente manera:

pagina club-accion.php

```
    //VARIABLES IMNPORANTE
    $club = isset($_POST['club']) ? $_POST['club'] : NULL;
    $liga = isset($_POST['liga']) ? $_POST['liga'] : NULL;
    $division = isset($_POST['division']) ? $_POST['division'] : NULL;

    require_once('conectar.ini.php');  
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT c.*, l.nombre_liga, d.division FROM club c LEFT JOIN liga l ON l.id_liga = c.liga_c LEFT JOIN division d ON d.id_division = c.division_c WHERE club = '$club' AND liga_c = '$liga' AND division_c='$division'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 0){
    }
    else{
        
    //VUELVO A COMNSULTAR PARA TRAER LOS NOMBRES Y NO LOS ID DE LOS CLUBES, LIGAS Y DIVISIONES
    $base = "SELECT c.*, l.nombre_liga, d.division FROM club c LEFT JOIN liga l ON l.id_liga = c.liga_c LEFT JOIN division d ON d.id_division = c.division_c WHERE club = '$club' AND liga_c = '$liga' AND division_c='$division'";
    
    $nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
    $crow= mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);

    $club = $crow['club'];
    $nombre_liga = $crow['nombre_liga'];
    $division = $crow['division'];
    
    mysqli_close($conn);
    //ENVIO POR GET LOS VALORES
    header('Location:club-registrado.php?club=' . urlencode($club) . '&nombre_liga=' . urlencode($nombre_liga) . '&division=' . urlencode($division));

}
```

pagina que recibo el mensaje de cub registrado: club-registrado.php

```
<?php
        
    //RECIBO LOS VALORES POR GET
    $club = isset($_GET['club']) ? $_GET['club'] : "";
    $nombre_liga = isset($_GET['nombre_liga']) ? $_GET['nombre_liga'] : "";
    $division = isset($_GET['division']) ? $_GET['division'] : "";

?>
<!--AQUI MUESTRO LOS NOMBRE Y NO LOS ID-->
<h4>
<?php echo "El Club <strong>".$club."</strong> en la liga <strong>".$nombre_liga."</strong> en la division <strong>".$division."</strong>"; ?>
</h4>
```